# Modal loaded from backend is being covered by other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html fragment that is being loaded by the backend into the `main` div of my page. It contains a `modal` that appears when a link is clicked on. The issue is, is that the `modal` is able to be covered up by other elements on the page. Setting the `z-index` is useless, because if an element in the `header` has a higher `z-index` than the `main` div, the `modal` will show up behind the `header`, regardless of its `z-index`. I'm currently solving the problem by using javascript (jQuery) to `clone` the `modal`, appending the clone to the `body`, and then deleting the original `modal`. This seems like a hacky workaround and could cause potential problems, is there a better way to do this? How do modals usually get loaded so that they don't encounter this issue?

Here's a jsfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kraxF/

Here's the HTML, as you can see, the modal is pretty low in the DOM tree, and may be covered up by elements in the header or footer or main, if they have a higher z-index than "loaded-by-backend".

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        Main
        <div id="loaded-by-backend">
            <div id="modal">
                Modal
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, modal dialogs are added to the end of the markup (before the closing `body` tag.)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/kraxF/1/

Comment: @Kevin I agree, modals should be loaded at the end of markup. But, that's not how this modal is being loaded. It's not my decision, unfortunately, so I have to make the best of it.

Comment: @Westie: The problem is that z-index is always inherited by the parent, so if main is at 50, and header is at 200, then the modal inside of main will never be above header, if it's at 900 or 9999 or whatever.

Comment: @Westie: What if I want a nav in my header to show as a dropdown above main? Your z-index solution breaks that. In my original jsfiddle, I put the z-index of main below header for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change CSS, just remove `position:relative` from `#main`.
http://jsfiddle.net/kraxF/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the html or CSS on any part of the page. Right now, things work fine, but there could eventually be a case where the page changes and things break, such as the modal being loaded on to a page where the main div is set relative. The `clone` solution above is one way of making the modal element position above anything else, regardless of other conditions. I'm looking for another solution that has the same effect, but would be better/less hacky. Thanks for your answer though :)